# How to reduce the number of designed lifeforms whilst still giving the impression of an endless amount?

Tags: creature-design, worldbuilding-process

I am not sure if this is a worldbuilding or story writing issue but I am wondering how I can show the vast amount of life throughout a volume of space without having to go into full detail.

There is an empire which rules the volume of space and some advanced species not of the empire which I have already designed and additional characters and species should not be too time consuming but it is creating ecosystems for all of the millions/billions of habitable planets that I am not sure how to reduce whilst still giving the audience the feeling a universe teaming with life.

I have started to design the ecosystems for a few planets that are not inhabited by advanced species and aim to give the impression that intelligent advanced species are rare but less advanced life can easily evolve and does occur in high numbers.

I considered having planets that the story takes part on having a detailed ecosystem and other planets or lifeforms being mentioned briefly so that the audience knows there is a lot of variety of life out there other than on those detailed planets but even then there will need to be a lot of brief descriptions to convey the vastness of life.

By what methods can I reduce the number of lifeforms that need to be designed but still show enough that it feels like an endless amount of varied life exists?

Comment: Worldbuilding is about facts of your world. If you are asking how you can show a smaller number and give the impression of a larger number, you're not creating a fact of your world, you're asking how to represent that fact this is going to be different if you're writing a story, making a game, composing a concept album.  This is not about worldbuilding. It's a question about fixing a world you've made up in a fictional form. You may want to try asking this on writing.SE.

Comment: This could work on our sister site [writing.se]. (Take their tour, read-up in their help centre etc..)

Comment: Is this for a story or for a game?  Is the game Spore?

Comment: @Willk Its a graphic novel. I probably should have mentioned that as answers are about writing, which do still help when it comes to describing life in just dialogue but often in comics anything that is described will be accompanied by images. And it is harder to skip details in visual media.

Comment: This is more a creative writing question, but what you basically need to do is "trick" the reader into thinking that there is far more worldbuilding than you've actually done and let their own minds fill in the details. One (basic) way to do this could be to build a very small amount of creatures very well and use them in clever ways so that the reader then assumes all the creatures and ecosystems you off-handedly mention in your universe were given this same depth of detail. Similarly, ascribe one detailed unique fact for every creature or ecosystem you mention and then let the reader imagine

Comment: This depends quite a bit on the nature of the story. Novels can get away with quite a bit simply for their lack of visual depiction, whereas film and video games require much more. Ttrpg can, to some extent, rely on the improv nature of the media. Still art (comic books) are almost as bad as film, except that 24 frames per second tends to just require that much more volume than 32 pages per issue. Strategies to reduce the workload are highly dependent on the nature of the story... so just what sort are you doing?

Comment: Also, (controversial hot take) worldbuilding isn't *that* important when telling a story, or at least, it should be subservient to **Character** and **Plot**. Detail for detail's sake is fun to dream up and we love to do it here on SE, but in storytelling its almost always fat that an author wants to trim away. Ideally, you want *just* enough worldbuilding that the "iceberg principle" applies, and every part of the worldbuilding you do should serve your storytelling somehow (Chekhov's gun)

Answer (score 4):

### Exemplarity

When describing a place, have the narration pick a seemingly random piece of fauna and flora, and make it an example for how it has adapted to the environment. The reader will fill the gaps with the canvas of their mind. Like... let me show at an example I just make up.

> Vulis Vulis nordicus
>
> This animal the size of a housecat stands as a good example for the survivability in the toxic environment of MX241-B's fauna: The dull red fur is coated in an almost rubbery grease, allowing the caustic rain to wash over it without ever touching its skin and at the same time to blend in on the red iron rocks of its northern homes. Sharp eyes with horizontally slit pupils allow them to act in the harsh light of day while opening wide at night, making them the apex predator.

I described *one* animal, but it gives people things that they can transfer to other animals we *know* to create something. Vulis are predators, so they feed on something smaller, something... the size of rodents. They have greasy fur, which would be a trait that quite some other animals on MX241-B share. The caustic rains will make us think of plants that shed the water from their surface to stop it from staying there.

Answer (score 2):

/Its a graphic novel./

**ALIEN ZOO!**

[Lois tours the alien zoo at the Fortress of Solitude](https://retcon-punch.com/2014/03/26/superman-unchained-6/)
[image: supermans zoo]

I love it when we get to see Superman's zoo at the Fortress of Solitude.  I guess Superman is the zookeeper too; solitude you know.  Or maybe robots?

In any case - if this is graphics and you have an alien zoo you can go wild as in this frame.  All sorts of critters.  No explanation for what they all are.  Alien critters!  You can have your action in the Zuniverse and show people the variety there is.

I think that is the Lorax down there reaching for Lois' knee.  So that is where it went!

Comment: Yeah that's true, a busy nature scene does not need the full details and description. I was actually thinking about an endless museum of life/zoo.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question.
I have come across multiple novels in which there exist many nonsentient species. The trick (in my opinion) is to write brief descriptions and add as few species as possible (to avoid confusing the reader), while still implying an underlying depth. Short lists help as well, but honestly, the less you describe, the more the reader will believe exists.

Read the following four sentences:

1. The rotten stump was positively infested with insects.
2. The rotten stump was positively infested with red ants, termites, arachnids, and many other similar critters.
3. The rotten stump was positively infested with insects of all kinds--beady-eyed arachnids, toxic ants, and venomous termites, among others.
4. The rotting stump was positively infested with beady-eyed arachnids (8-inch long fuzzy gray creatures that can outrun a fully grown man), toxic ants (the type that secrete a powerful neurotoxin, 10.5 milligrams of which is enough to kill an elephant), venomous termites (which are renowned for their ability to stun a fully grown wolf with their stingers), along with [insert tedious list of insects and descriptions here]....

The first one gives you the gist of the idea without much elaboration.

The second one describes what species were in there, along with stating that there are 'many other similar critters.' This allows the mind to ponder what else might be in there. You know that any other creatures in there are similar to those described but could be widely different.

The *third* one is probably the best of all. It describes the species by saying that one is beady-eyed, one is toxic, and another is venomous. I also said there were insects of all kinds, implying that my list is incomplete and selective. Now that I have conveniently added adjectives, your mind has even more information to digest when considering what else could be in there. Without diving into a taxonomical journey that describes all the insects and subspecies of insects in the stump (in nauseating detail), you now have: a) A general idea of what is in there; b) The knowledge that there is something unknown in there; and c) Details about the known insects that could help when thinking about the unknown insects.

The fourth one is just an encouragement to stop reading the book and/or try to go slap the author across the face. It is interesting, but only for the author. The reader's not going to care about every detail of an animal. For one, it implies that the author believes them to be devoid of imagination. And it gets extremely dull after a certain point, especially in a novel like a mystery novel, in which every detail could be a clue.

So, I would caution you from writing overly-tedious descriptions of species. If you write carefully and leave things intentionally vague--while still dropping helpful information--then you won't have to worry about it. The reader will detect the depth  of what you *haven't* said, which will be even more powerful than an exhaustive list and scientific description of every species of crab that lives on the Crabby Beach.

Hope this helps!